# Looping through every nodes name

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a lot of objects in different positions in my scene dae file, with names like: "Ball01, Ball02... Ball15" And i would like to make them all for example have a physics body of their own shape and in their own position. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: You could use `self.children` which returns all child `SKNodes`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`SCNNode.childNodes(passingTest:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1407982-childnodespassingtest) in combination with `SCNNode.name` to find these nodes easily.

Comment: Can you show me an example?